# Add custom commands to CMakeLists.txt file

Tags: cmake, command

Recently I have switched my project compilation procedure from `make` to `cmake`. I would like to add custom non-compilation related commands to my `CMakeLists.txt` file. These commands should be inherited from classical `Makefile`. Commands that I would like to re-use in `CMakeLists.txt` are:

```
CODE=main
ARCHIVE=$(CODE)_`date +%F`.tar.bz2
BACKUP=$(HOME)/backup/src/$(CODE)

run:
    { time ./$(CODE); } 2> $(CODE)_time

rerun:  fresh run

fresh:
    rm -rvf $(CODE)_time *~ fort.* *.ver
    rm -rvf coef? enc skin_depths log input_params.out

clean:  fresh
    rm -rvf $(CODE) *.o *.a *.mod

backup: *
    tar -cjvf $(ARCHIVE) $?
    tar -tjvf $(ARCHIVE)
    mv  -vf   $(ARCHIVE) $(BACKUP)
    ls  -lrth $(BACKUP)
```

How may I transfer these commands to `CMakeLists.txt` so that they will be automatically inserted into `cmake` generated `Makefile`?

### CMakeLists.txt

```
# Minimum cmake version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

# Project name
project(main Fortran)

# Toolchain selection, possible arguments: Intel, GNU
SET(Toolchain GNU)

# Compiler selection
include(CMakeForceCompiler) 

# GNU compilers
if(${Toolchain} MATCHES GNU)
  CMAKE_FORCE_Fortran_COMPILER(gfortran "GNU Fortran Compiler")
  set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "-g -O0 -fimplicit-none -fbounds-check -fbacktrace ${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS}")
endif(${Toolchain} MATCHES GNU)

# Source code files
SET(src variables.F90
        init.F90
        io.F90)

# Main executable
ADD_EXECUTABLE(${PROJECT_NAME} ${src})

# EoF: CMakeLists.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:add_custom_target) and/or [`ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:add_custom_command) commands, e.g.:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(myTarget
                  COMMAND firstCommand arg1 arg2
                  COMMAND secondCommand arg1 arg2 arg3)
```

Then you can use `make myTarget`.